# Add options when moving from NetCore 2 Newtonsoft JSON to the new JSON API in NetCore 3

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I recently upgraded my Entity Framework Core project from DotNet Core 2.2 to 3.1.

I am using newtonsoft json, but I am wondering if I still need these two lines that are causing the errors.  Here are those two lines:

```
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    });
```

And here is the error:

> 'JsonOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SerializerSettings' and no accessible extension method
>   'SerializerSettings' accepting a first argument of type 'JsonOptions'
>   could be found

Does the new Microsoft JSON library have anything that would ignore reference loops and null values like Newtonsoft JSON does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of `System.Text.Json`  and this feature might be addressed in .net 5 which is slated for Nov 2020 :

Reference :  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38579 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41002

Currently the workaround is to use Newtonsoft JSON instead . To use `Newtonsoft.Json` in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC project :

- Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package.
- Update `Startup.ConfigureServices` to call `AddNewtonsoftJson` and set settings :

  ```
  services.AddMvc()
  .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
          options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
          options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
      });
  ```